# Plotting angled hyperboloid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot a hyperboloid of the form

`SQRT((x - x_i)^2 + (y - y_i)^2 + (z - z_i)^2) - SQRT((x - x_j)^2 + (y - y_j)^2 + (z - z_j)^2) = R`

This is a hyperboloid between the two focii i and j. Unfortunately all the advice I can find deals with the case where the focii are along the z axis. Is it possible to do what I want in matlab?

Comment: Does [this discussion on Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16688-how-to-draw-a-hyperboloid) help you? It appears that you have to set up your coordinates a bit more carefully. If this is not what you are after, please consider clarifying your question and maybe providing a sketch of what you are looking for.

Comment: You oould try this matlab exchange file: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23623-ezimplot3--implicit-3d-functions-plotter . You shoudl be able to plot any implicit 3D plot with it.

Comment: Bloody hell, that's brilliant! Thanks!